# Strip column in csv files and save to different folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file, csv

I have a folder with some csv files within it. By mistake, an extra column got populated onto the csv files. Now i need to export these files into a separate folder without this extra column. Column name is consistent across all csvs. So a csv like

```
"Col1","Col2","ColRemove"
"1","2","3"
"2","3","4"
"3","4","5"
```

Needs to be moved to a different file/folder as

```
"Col1","Col2"
"1","2"
"2","3"
"3","4"
```

What is the easiest way to achieve the same ? If it was a single file, i would have followed steps as mentioned [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/10/17/easily-remove-columns-from-a-csv-file-by-using-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Your example data is not consistent. Look at line 2 in the source file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select-Object has an -ExcludeProperty parameter that you can leverage for that:

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv |
foreach {
 Import-csv $_ |
 select * -ExcludeProperty ColRemove |
 Export-Csv "c:\NewDir\$($_.name)" -NoTypeInformation
 }
```

Comment: Get-ChildItem C:..\*.csv |
foreach {
 Import-csv $_ |
 select -ExcludeProperty ColRemove |
 Export-Csv C:\...\$_ -NoTypeInformation
 }

Comment: At line:5 char:12
+  Export-Csv <<<<  C:\...\$_ -NoTypeInformation
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Export-Csv], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: Are you trying to export back to the same file you're importing?

Comment: No.. to a different folder ..i am specifying the full path to the new folder. Should i use a \\ instead of \

Comment: I updated the answer to use the .name property of the file object.  That should fix the error.

Comment: Ok.. now i get the files. But the column that needs to be removed is included too

Comment: my csv has quoted identifiers.. Does that impact?

Comment: ok.. after select and before -ExcludeProperty, a star was missing :)

Comment: * has been added.  How can the column-to-be-removed be specified, if say it is column 2 that needs to be removed?

Comment: Removing a column by position is a much different proposition than the original question. I would start a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%f in (*.csv) do (    
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in ("%%f") do @echo %%a,%%b>>"%%~dpnf-new.csv"
)
```